# Account on Gmail that I can log into, but not receive email on?

Tags: gmail, google-account

I have an additional email address **additionalemail@gmail.com** associated with my Google Groups account that I use as sender on some groups. I can use this account to log into gmail by providing additionalemail@gmail.com as the username, but when I log in I really log into my **realemail@gmail.com** account and need to use the same password.

I'm unable to receive email on additionalemail@gmail.com and email to this account bounces. When I try to claim the account using Accounts and Import -> Send mail as I don't receive the verification email.

It looks like my additionalemail@gmail.com only works like an alias for my realemail@gmail.com, but I would rather also have the opportunity to receive email also on this separate account that Google Groups has as an option for subscription.

Would this be possible somehow?

Comment: @Rishbabh I think some of them still requires answers so I would like to keep them open. E.g. this question took over a year to get answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See additionalemail@gmail.com is an alias for realemail@gmail.com, which implies that addtionalemail@gmail.com is something like: real.e.mail@gmail.com re.alemail@gmail.com or realemail+anything@gmail.com

This is not a separate GMail account and so you cannot receive separate emails for this. You do not have a separate inbox for this. You can create a filter so that the emails sent to the additionalemail go to a particular label.

You can try creating accounts on different sites using additionalemail, you try to subscribe to something using this additional email.

If you go to GMail>Settings>Accounts and Imports you can add additionalemail under the Send Mail as and send e-mails as additionalemail (but the complete header of the sent email would reveal your realemail@gmail.com).